# How to delete all packages from a repository and then delete the repository and then delete the signing key?

Tags: package-management, 21.10, mono, add-apt-repository

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10. I made a mistake and downloaded Mono that's supposed to be used on a older version and now it's giving me error messages like:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg/ returned an error code (1)
```

I downloaded the official Mono repository and its key from here:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mono-on-ubuntu-20-04/ and installed mono-complete with the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main'
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

Comment: What commands have you used the exact ones. You do not download a repository you add a link to the PPA so your question is confusing.

Comment: I followed what the tutorial said.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply but I am not familiar with the terminology of linux so I just assumed it's was called donwloading. Everytime i tried to use Sudo apt-get --fix-broken  install it just gives me a error message

Answer (score 0):

To remove the official Mono repository and its signing key, remove mono-complete and clean up afterwards run the following commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main'
sudo apt-key del "3FA7 E032 8081 BFF6 A14D  A29A A6A1 9B38 D3D8 31EF"
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove --purge mono-complete
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```